# What happens when the latent heat of a substance is more than the specific heat capacity of its liquid form?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, phase-diagram

i came upon a question involving mixing a given of 15 degree celcius  water with a given amount of ice, they asked me about the final temperature of mixture... i solved this question by applying the concept of "heat loss by water = heat gained by ice" by using both latent and specific heat, my answer was a negative value after 3-5 reattempts but the options were a positive temperature, i know that im applying the right concept of heat loss and gain but the answer im getting is wrong

**then i calculated the specific heat capacity and latent heat capacity, and from there i concluded that latent heat is more than the specific heat.**
so here is my question
why the answer to this question is zero degrees, what does this above conclusion had to do with the correct result?

Comment: Typically the heat due to temperature change is negligible compared to latent heat. Therefore, the typical end state is phase coexistence between liquid and solid whose proportions are determined by the different initial temperatures. At standard pressure, the phase coexistence can inly happen at $0°C$

Comment: please can you elaborate, im very new to this part of physics

Comment: Essentially, as long as you have both liquid and solid water, you must be at $0°C$. It is often the case, because the energy supplied from raising the temperature of ice/lowering the temperature of water is typically not enough to completely freeze the water/melt the ice. This is due to the large value of latent heat compared to heat capacity of the typically small temperature increments.

Comment: Try doing the math in detail, things will become clearer

Comment: @ShaishavSharma I'm not sure how you applied the equation "heat loss by water = heat gained by ice", since you didn't show your calculations or provide enough information on the initial (pre mixing) conditions such as the mass of the water, and the mass and temperature of the ice, both before mixing. Without that information,  all of the following are possible outcomes of the mixing:

1. A combination of water and ice, which will necessarily be at 0$^{0}$C 
2. All water at 0$^{0}$C
3. All ice at 0$^{0}$C
4. All water at temperature > 0$^{0}$C
5. All ice at temperature < 0$^{0}$C